# How to get the min date if when a string showed?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, data-manipulation

Hello Stackoverflow Community,
I am having trouble finding out how to get the min date if when a a string showed up. For example I know how to get min date by doing df['date'].min() but I have a column named system which has the names of all of the systems. I am trying to see when was the most earliest system and this was my code.
df.groupby('date')['system'].min() but it did not work could someone please help me?

Here is my code that i tried but I got an error
`df.groupby('date')['system'].min()`

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there sample dataframe (in text form) and expected output?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Remember, we can't help you if we can't see what you've tried!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah without a dataframe example, it's hard to answer and understand your question correctly! But I believe the solution is:

```py
df.groupby('system')['date'].min()
```